# i want the progress bar start animation when it is viewed

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar, counter

heyy i am with a problem with this ...i want to start progressbar progress when it comes to viewport .... with percentage text and bar....the demo is here

```
$('.bar-percentage[data-percentage]').each(function () {
 var progress = $(this);
 var percentage = Math.ceil($(this).attr('data-percentage'));



$({countNum: 0}).animate({countNum: percentage}, {
duration: 3000,
easing:'swing',


step: function() {
  // What todo on every count
var pct = '';
if(percentage == 0){
  pct = Math.floor(this.countNum) + '%';
}else{
  pct = Math.floor(this.countNum) + "%";
}

progress.text(pct) && progress.siblings().children().css('width', pct);
    }
   });
 });
```

http://cssdeck.com/labs/percentage-bar

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

This is full functioning for you, with this code your progress bars start animating when first progress bar viewed and then don't animate again

```
    function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

var IsViewed = false;

$(document).scroll(function () {

  if(isScrolledIntoView('#bar-1') && !IsViewed){
$('.bar-percentage[data-percentage]').each(function () {
  var progress = $(this);
  var percentage = Math.ceil($(this).attr('data-percentage'));
  $({countNum: 0}).animate({countNum: percentage}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
      // What todo on every count
    var pct = '';
    if(percentage == 0){
      pct = Math.floor(this.countNum) + '%';
    }else{
      pct = Math.floor(this.countNum+1) + '%';
    }
    progress.text(pct) && progress.siblings().children().css('width',pct);
    }
  });
});
    IsViewed = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: can u give me the full functioning code please??

Comment: many many tnx to u..but it is not showing any percentage or bar :( :(

Comment: in your cssdeck link replace my javascript functions with yours and set margin-top:1000px for 'bar-1', then you will see it works. my code works when progress bars don't appear in first view and you must scroll to see them, notice me if it's still doesn't work